# Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy values from one work book to current work book but i get the error:

> Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

I tried a lot but not get a solution any one please help me out

```
Sub Update()

Dim sPath As String
Dim sValue As String
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim strName As String

strName = ActiveSheet.Name ' Explicitly provide the sheet name
sPath = "C:\Users\nikhil.surendran\Desktop\1"
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\nikhil.surendran\Desktop\3" & ".xlsx")
sValue = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B5").Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B5").Value = sValue
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B5").Value` returns an array of `Variant`s. You cannot store that in a `String`. Declare `sValue` as `Variant` or `Variant()`.